# Sugar CRM 6.5 API

Tags: arrays, json, sugarcrm

I am new to the Sugar CRM 6.5 API. I am having trouble getting my url to post data to the leads module in Sugar. Here is the posting url,

```
https://yoursite/service/v4_1/rest.php?method=set_entry&input_type=JSON&response_type=JSON&rest_data={"name_value_list":{"last_name":"Peter","status":"New","email1":"test@test.com","lead_source":"test"},"module_name":"Leads"}
```

Here is my response,

```
{
    "id": "459bf4a2-0b3b-5857-feb5-56fe81e621eb",
    "entry_list": {
        "modified_by_name": {
            "name": "modified_by_name",
            "value": "admin"
        },
        "id": {
            "name": "id",
            "value": "459bf4a2-0b3b-5857-feb5-56fe81e621eb"
        },
        "name": {
            "name": "name",
            "value": " "
        },
        "date_entered": {
            "name": "date_entered",
            "value": "2016-04-01 14:10:12"
        },
        "date_modified": {
            "name": "date_modified",
            "value": "2016-04-01 14:10:12"
        },
        "modified_user_id": {
            "name": "modified_user_id",
            "value": "1"
        },
        "created_by": {
            "name": "created_by",
            "value": "1"
        },
        "deleted": {
            "name": "deleted",
            "value": 0
        },
        "full_name": {
            "name": "full_name",
            "value": " "
        },
        "do_not_call": {
            "name": "do_not_call",
            "value": false
        },
        "converted": {
            "name": "converted",
            "value": false
        },
        "lead_source": {
            "name": "lead_source",
            "value": "Web Site"
        },
        "status": {
            "name": "status",
            "value": "New"
        },
        "jjwg_maps_lat_c": {
            "name": "jjwg_maps_lat_c",
            "value": 0
        },
        "jjwg_maps_lng_c": {
            "name": "jjwg_maps_lng_c",
            "value": 0
        }
    }
}
```

When I view the leads, I get a blank record created. Any idea's, Thanks

Comment: have you tried to pass the module_name param before the name_value_list in the request?

Answer (score 0):

The format of name_value_list is as follow:

```
{
  "name_value_list":
     "full_name": {"name": "full_name", "value": "John"}
}
```